# How to give an individual item in an array its own unique state using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm working through fullstackopen and i'm on exercise 1.13. I am struggling to understand how to implement a way to update the state for individual items in an array [anecdotes].

Each anecdote has is allowed a number of votes.

I can increment votes, but it increments votes for all.

https://fullstackopen.com/en/part1/a_more_complex_state_debugging_react_apps#exercises-1-6-1-14

The below code is what they provide as a hint to implement, as well as some hints about using arr.fill()

```js
const points = [1, 4, 6, 3]

const copy = [...points]
// increment the value in position 2 by one
copy[2] += 1
```

**Goal:** I want to vote for a displayed random anecdote and store that result so the next time I view the random anecdote it has the same number of votes I added previously.

I can manage to implement the button functionality to increate the votes by one but this only leads to all anecdotes having the same number of votes.

What would the data structure look like?
How would you update state in a situation involving a complex data structures?

Below is my code:

```js
const App = () => {
  const anecdotes = [
    'If it hurts, do it more often',
    'Adding manpower to a late software project makes it later!',
    'The first 90 percent of the code accounts for the first 90 percent of the development time...The remaining 10 percent of the code accounts for the other 90 percent of the development time.',
    'Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.',
    'Premature optimization is the root of all evil.',
    'Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.'
  ]

  const votings = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  let copy = [...votings]

  
  const handleVotes = () => {
    setVotes(votes + 1)
    console.log(votings)
    votings[selected] = votings[selected] + votes
    console.log(votings)
    copy = [...votings]
    return copy
  }
   
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)
  const [votes, setVotes] = useState(0)

  const getRandomAnecdote = () => {
    let randomVal = Math.floor(Math.random(selected) * anecdotes.length)
    setSelected(randomVal)
    console.log(randomVal)
  }


  return (
    <div>
      {anecdotes[selected]}
      <br></br>
      {votings[selected]}
      <br/> 
      <p>This anecdote has: {copy[selected]} votes</p>
      <button onClick={getRandomAnecdote}>Random</button>
      <button onClick={handleVotes}>Vote</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT:

HERE IS THE WORKING CODE THANKS TO CRISTIANS RESPONSE BELOW:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const anecdotes = [
    'If it hurts, do it more often',
    'Adding manpower to a late software project makes it later!',
    'The first 90 percent of the code accounts for the first 90 percent of the development time...The remaining 10 percent of the code accounts for the other 90 percent of the development time.',
    'Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.',
    'Premature optimization is the root of all evil.',
    'Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.'
  ]

  const handleVotes = () => {
    const votesCopy = [...votes]
    votesCopy[selected] += 1
    setVotes(votesCopy)
  }

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)
  const [votes, setVotes] = useState([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

  const getRandomAnecdote = () => {
    let randomVal = Math.floor(Math.random(selected) * anecdotes.length)
    setSelected(randomVal)
    console.log(randomVal)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {anecdotes[selected]}
      <br/> 
      <p>This anecdote has: {votes[selected]} votes</p>
      <button onClick={getRandomAnecdote}>Random</button>
      <button onClick={handleVotes}>Vote</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Keeping the data as an array is fine. You're probably doing something wrong when increasing the votes. So unless you show us that part, it is hard to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Okay, I just updated the post with my code.

Comment: So will I need to change const [votes, setVotes] to a useState([])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the issue is that you initialize the state(votes) with 0. Instead, you should initialize that with an array of zeros.

```js
//votes[i] represents the number of votes for the i-th anecdote
const [votes, setVotes] = useState([0,0,0,0,0,0])
```

Now when you handle a vote:

```js
 const handleVotes = () => {
    //you make a copy of the votes
    const votesCopy = [...votes]
    
    //then increase the votes for the selected anecdote
    votesCopy[selected] += 1;
    
    //and finally update the state
    setVotes(votesCopy);
  }
```